# TypeError: read_csv() takes from 0 to 1 positional arguments but 2 were given

Tags: python, csv

What am I missing here? I have tried looking at the code but I do not know where the extra positional argument is located at,

```
def read_csv(path: str = None) -> List[List] :
    lead = Path(__file__).parent / f'../data/{path}'
    entries = []

    print('Reading dataset...')
    with open(lead, 'r') as csvfile:
        video_reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
        for row in video_reader:
            entries.append(row)

    return print(entries)
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:/Users/MEDIAMARKT/Desktop/booking/__main__.py", line 15, in <module>
        gui = GUI()
      File "C:\Users\MEDIAMARKT\Desktop\booking\gui.py", line 22, in init
          self.upload_data()
        File "C:\Users\MEDIAMARKT\Desktop\booking\gui.py", line 84, in upload_data
            self.booking.read_csv(path)
          TypeError: read_csv() takes from 0 to 1 positional arguments but 2 were given
```

Comment: Can you show the full traceback? Also `return print(..)` will always return None

Comment: sure:                                                                                                                       
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/MEDIAMARKT/Desktop/booking/__main__.py", line 15, in <module>
    gui = GUI()
  File "C:\Users\MEDIAMARKT\Desktop\booking\gui.py", line 22, in __init__
    self.upload_data()
  File "C:\Users\MEDIAMARKT\Desktop\booking\gui.py", line 84, in upload_data
    self.booking.read_csv(path)

Comment: What is `self.booking`? You should show this class. You do understand that class functions always have an explicit `self` parameter?

Comment: Well the self.booking belongs to a method which is inside a class called GUI which is by itself huge but this is the mthod to which 'self.booking' belongs to:''''   def upload_data(self) -> None:
        """
        Creates an instance of the Booking system.
        """
        path = os.path.join(os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), os.pardir)),
                            'data/Hotel_Reviews_EU.csv')
        self.booking = hotel_types.Booking([], [])
        self.booking.read_csv(path)

        # Instantiate the output
        self.output = ''''

Comment: Im trying to put the code in between the ' ' but it isnt working

Comment: Please stop using comments to add code. [edit] the post instead

Answer (score 0):

Your error is elsewhere, not in the snippet provided, since as a standalone function, that code should work fine.

Looking at your traceback, you've introduced classes, so reading your error

> 2 were given

When you call a class function, the instance of that class is **always** supplied as a parameter

example

```
class Foo:
  def bar(self, other=None):  # self is a required argument for instance methods
    pass

xyz = 'something'
booking = Foo()
booking.bar()  # 1 parameter provided - the instance itself
booking.bar(xyz)  # 2 parameters provided - the instance and the string
```

So, to fix your function, you need to add the self parameter, even if you don't plan on using it.

Before, the `path` variable you used wasn't actually a string, so the type checker should have been throwing an error as well

```
class Booking():
  def read_csv(self, path:str = None) -> List[List]:
    # TODO
    return []
```

Comment: Oh so what Im missing is using the self argument, ah I get it now

Comment: But when I change it as you did it I get a new error: OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'C:\\Users\\MEDIAMARKT\\Desktop\booking\\..\\data\\C:\\Users\\MEDIAMARKT\\Desktop\\\\data\\Hotel_Reviews_EU.csv'

Comment: Because `..\\data` has your C drive repeated again. That isn't a problem with my answer, but the parameter you gave as the path

Comment: Why is `C:\\ ` in the middle of that path?

Comment: Also `\booking` only has one backslash, therefore `\b` is interpreted as a backspace character.

Comment: @OneCricketeer And how do I assign it an correct path then?

Comment: @JohnGordon But how can I make the \b double?

Comment: @Michael You should not be using `/  f'../data/{path}'`. You should instead use `/ 'data' / get_file_name(path)`. Or, you need to pass the filename rather than the full absolute path

Comment: @OneCricketeer Well what I want is to iterate through each line of the CSV file which creates instances two classes that I have, and adding these objects to two attributes of the booking class.

Comment: I understand what you want, I guess, but I suggest creating a new post with your specific issue doing that because my answer here was for your original error

Comment: @OneCricketeer But if I where to use your way of doing it `/ 'data' / get_file_name(path)` Then It wouldnt work if someone else opened it from another computer.

Comment: Why not? `Path(__file__).parent` returns the current script path, on any machine. Then you append the `data` folder. (Note: You can remove `..` if you used `.parent.parent`), then you need to append **just the filename**. The comment you provided above indicates that your path parameter is the **full path**. I do not have the rest of your code to tell you why that is

Comment: @OneCricketeer Well when I write `lead = Path(__file__).parent / 'data' / get_file_name(path)` I need to define `get_file_name` as the folder in which the CSV folder is located at right?

Comment: Given that `path` is a string variable, and not a Path-like object, then yes.

Comment: You could try using `path.split(os.sep)[-1]`, though

Comment: @OneCricketeer So something like this?     `def read_csv(self, path: str = None) -> List[List] :
        
        path.split(os.sep)[-1]
        get_file_name = "C:\Users\MEDIAMARKT\data\Hotel_Reviews_EU.csv"
        lead = Path(__file__).parent / 'data' / get_file_name(path)`

Comment: Nope. `lead = Path(__file__).parent / 'data' / path.split(os.sep)[-1]`

Comment: @OneCricketeer It gives me the following error then `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\MEDIAMARKT\\Desktop\\booking\\data\\data\\Hotel_Reviews_EU.csv`  Do you have any clue why its going over data twice?

Comment: Again, I don't know what your `path` variable actually is, but it seems like you already put `data` folder as part of it